# How to find the closest next sibling that matches selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following example structure where there are some groups with different `headerx` class but same class at the `group` and at the `groupxbottom`, and unknown number of `<li>`s between them.

I get all the headers with specific `headerx` class:

```
let headers = $('.header1');
```

Then I need to hide the matching `groupxbottom` for each group.

I have the selector that matches `groupxbottom` using `match()`. The problem is that it matches all `groupxbottom` elements, but I only need to select 1 `groupxbottom` which is the next closest sibling.

Assuming I already extract the correct class name and it's saved in `selector`, how can I match it with the next closest sibling while iterating headers:

```
headers.each(function() {
   $(this).(.. use selector for next closest sibling only ..).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="header1 group1">Header1 Group1</li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1bottom">Group 1 bottom</li>

<li class="header1 group2">Header1 Group2</li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2bottom">Group2 bottom</li>

<li class="header2 group1">Header2 Group1</li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1bottom">Group1 bottom</li>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. Next time please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use `siblings()` **https://api.jquery.com/siblings/**

```js
let headers = $('.header');

headers.each(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.group1bottom').hide();
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: lightpink;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.group1bottom {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="header group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1bottom"></li>

<li class="header group2"></li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2bottom"></li>

<li class="header group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1bottom"></li>
```

Comment: It's not good in my case because I want each time in the iteration in `each` to match exactly the closest next sibling and not all siblings

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/), along with a partial [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), can find the group elements. Then we just grab the first one in the set.

Note that it's not necessary to use distinct class names. They can all be the same.

```js
$('li.header').each(function() {
  const groupEl = $(this).nextAll('[class*="bottom"]').first();
  console.log($(this).text() + ': ' + groupEl.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="header group1">Header 1</li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1bottom">Group 1 bottom</li>

<li class="header group2">Header 2</li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2"></li>
<li class="group2bottom">Group 2 bottom</li>

<li class="header group3">Header 3</li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group1"></li>
<li class="group3bottom">Group 3 bottom</li>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the post after it was marked as duplicate to make it more clear. I need specifically to choose the next closest sibling for the currently iterated element. Because if you look in the updated snippet in my post, there can be different `headerx` elements with same `groupx` elements

Comment: In this case I think I will use `nextUntil().last().next()`

Comment: No worries. Most of the jQuery methods have been covered on SO, so there are likely other duplicates. As long as you have a solution....